# HTML form POST not sending values

Tags: php, html

I know that there has been a couple of threads like that, I have looked through them and I can't seem to be able to find an answer. So I have a HTML form with a PHP file action and method POST. Here is the form:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <div class="contact-form bottom">
        <h2>Send a message</h2>
        <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form"  method="POST" action='http://creobox.ie/site/sendemail.php'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email Id">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Your text here"></textarea>
            </div>                        
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note, I tried using action ="sendemail.php" with no effect.

Then I am trying to GET the data in the PHP file, like so:

```
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));
```

The rest of the code is just composing the e-mail etc - this part works fine.

Am I missing something very simple? The code looks to be fine! I did echo on $name, $from, $subject and $message and all I got was

```
Details : <br/>
```

No errors showing up or anything... Thanks for any help!

Ok, so I tried to go with the AJAX... I modified my form to be

```
<div class="contact-form bottom">
                    <h2>Send a message</h2>
                    <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email Id">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Your text here"></textarea>
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Submit" href="javascript: void(0);" onclick = "sendMail();">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

and created a js function

```
function sendMail()
{
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var message = document.getElementById('message');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'sendemail.php',
            data: {
                'name' : name, 
                'email' : email, 
                'message' : message
            },
            success: function(json) { 
                if (json.status == 'S')
                    alert('Duplicates removed!');
                },
            error: function() {}
            });
}
```

But that doesn't work either... I just get a 304 - Not Modified error with a cached index page. This is starting to burn my brain! Could I be using an old version of jquery, hence all the problems?!

Comment: it is working you must have not entered any values in text boxes.

Comment: this is the output which i got

Comment: array(4) { ["name"]=> string(7) "fsafads" ["email"]=> string(14) "fsdaf@fads.com" ["message"]=> string(5) "sdfsa" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }

Comment: If something isn't working as it should, the first action should be to remove all `@` signs in front of your function calls. The `@` sign suppresses any errors thrown by PHP for that call, which kinda makes it harder to find errors.

Comment: for me everything works fine, can you show us more details? if there is any other code in php file

Comment: Maybe calling the action script with `action="http://creobox.ie/site/sendemail.php"` instead of `action='http://creobox.ie/site/sendemail.php'` ?

Comment: The thing is, the code reaches the sendemail.php file because anything that I input there is fed back. I did a var_dump ($_POST) and got an empty array so it's something to do with posting the values. Is there a setting in PHP that needs to be changed?

Comment: @MarinNedea tried that, no luck... I'll try that code on a local server, maybe it is something to do with the hosting settings..

Comment: @ArtleMaks, based on your ajax example... you have ` var name = document.getElementById('name');` but i do not see any `id="name"` in your form field. Same for the rest of fields. Also, since you submit all form fields, you can use in your ajax call `data: $("#main-contact-form").serialize();`

Comment: did you console.log() your name email and message before the ajax message.. are they being fetched properly?

Comment: @andrew you, Sir, have just solved my problem!! Changed it slightly but it works now, thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction! :)

Comment: @ArtleMaks glad i could help :)